# for videogular.js, is there a plugin for error handling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video, videogular

Using ng-onError = vm.fn(), as specified on the docs. 
If the src is not supported, is there a way to display that message (or custom message) on the video screen using videogular?